# Need name correction in my passport but I have a valid b1 visa

Tags: visas, usa, passports, b1-b2-visas

I got my passport made in Pune and they added my father's first and middle name to my name in it. My father's name is Girdhar Prasad Shrivastava and may name is Anita Srivastava. However, they made it Anita Girdhar Prasad Srivastava. 
Format: Given name - Anita Girdhar Prasad, Surname - Srivastava.

All my other legal documents and mark sheets have my name as Anita Srivastava. 
They even changed my father's name by adding my grandfather's name as his middle name under the guardian's name at the end of the passport.

I also traveled to the US once on B1 Visa which is still valid. But if I really want to correct my name and my father's name in the passport, is it possible? Will there be a problem in future US travels if I do so?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to re-issue your passport using the form [here](https://portal2.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/docAdvisor/reissuePassport).

> Will there be a problem in future US travels if I do so?

No, name changes/mistakes happen often so you should have no problems doing so if you explain the situation.